# Null Reference exception comes in debug mode, but works fine in release mode .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a desktop application that references a DLL. When I try to run the exe in debug mode it throws a run time exception at a particular step, but when I build the exe in release mode and run it directly then it doesn't throw any exception and works as expected.

Below code of my referenced DLL throws a null pointer exception for objdll variable when fDecrypt function is called.

```
   objdll = New NGTPLicense.clsKey
   objdll.psloggedinUser = sLoggedInUser
   objdll.piapploglevel = iAppLogLevel

   Call GetPrivateProfileString("AppManager Settings", "UserName", "", sRetString, 255, sIniFile)

   If objdll.fDecrypt(sRegVal, "newgen", sResult, sErrorDes) Then
       strUserName = sResult
   End If
```

What can be the possible reasons ?

Comment: An access violation in the native code can get translated to a managed NRE.  Could be a bug in the native code, but having no meaningful error checking on GetPrivateProfileString() is certainly one way to get that code to fall over.  Quite an evil function btw, not just because you declared it wrong, don't use it.  As-is it corrupts the GC heap by using a string instead of a properly sized StringBuilder, that can cause all kind of havoc.

Comment: I've also had this when my build/compile process (run button) didn't copy the DLL into my bin debug folder.